# dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

i am facing a situation where i can't find any solution. My website was working fine till i installed a new extension. After installing this extension my website and admin panel is not working. Actually i have installed lower version extension because i didn't noticed version and installed.

I am getting this stack trace :-

```
dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Trace:
#0 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#2 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#3 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#4 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#5 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#6 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#7 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#8 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#9 /home/krishangrover/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/krishangrover/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

I have done all the solution but no one is working. i have searched over google and searched on stackoverflow also. But no solution is working.

Comment: did you disable the extension ?

Comment: my admin panel is not working, how to disable this plugin

Comment: can you give me the name of extension ?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/attribute-manager.html

Comment: here is that attribute

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the extension created the problem. You need to disable the extension and try again.

For this you need to follow these steps

1. Go to the root directory of Magento
2. Open the directory `app/etc/modules/`.
3. You can find a file with a name `Ksv_Attributemanager.xml` there. Open that file.
4. There you can see a code like this `<active>true</active>`. Put `false` there.
5. Clear the cache and load the page again.

Let me know whether it makes any difference.

### EDIT

If you didn't find such file, then any one in those file is contributed by that extension. What you need to do is, open all files which does not start with `Mage`, and check for this code.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ksv_Attributemanager>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Ksv_Attributemanager>
    </modules>
</config>
```

There may be a `depend` node present along with this one. If you find such code in any one of the file, put false instead `true` and try again. (If this code present, that means that file is a part of that custom extension)

Comment: there is not any file named Ksv_Attributemanager.xml under app/etc/modules/ exist.

Comment: oops!! Ok.How many files there which does not starts with `Mage_`

Comment: 27 files that does not start with Mage_

Comment: there is file named "Ksv_Attributemanager-0.1.0.xml" under /var/package folder

Comment: Nope... Check in the location I specified. From there you need to start dig

Comment: i have searched in all modules, but didn't find any module with name "Ksv_Attributemanager"

Comment: that means that extension is not get properly download ! If that extension download properly, you can find a file correpsonding to that extension !!!. Put this quesion along with what you done now in this community http://magento.stackexchange.com/. You may get help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disabled the new extension. You can disable global configuration for that module so the module doesn't load by Magento.

Open global configuration file of the new extension:

Example:

Go to path **app\etc\modules\New_Extension.xml**

Set tag **active** to **false**.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <New_Extension>
           <active>false</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </New_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

If you get error while install new extension.
The new extension have to get data from database and You have not installed it so the error occur. You can check Magento Setup Resources for that extension.