# Magento 1.9.0.1: There has been an error processing your request: dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: database, magento, zend-db

I need some help please.. how can i solve this error in magento

**There has been an error processing your request**

**dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract**

Comment: possible duplicate of [dbModel read resource does not implement Zend\_Db\_Adapter\_Abstract in Magento ver 1.3.2.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362601/dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract-in-magento-ver). Also your question lacks essential details (magento version, what you did to make the error happen, ect...)

Comment: that is the old version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve by file permission of var directory.

Answer (score 0):

Give more information on your problem.

[dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract in Magento ver 1.3.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362601/dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract-in-magento-ver)

[dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545546/dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract)

[dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216231/dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract-in-magento)

Maybe one of those three will help? Top three results when I googled your error.

Comment: This is simply a comment on the original question.  Please post it as such when you are able.